# Facing problem converting XML using XSL to another xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to add the `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` this tag to my existing XML schema. I am trying to achieve this result by XSL transformation.But not getting the desired output. My schema sample and XSL is mentioned below.

XML:1

```
<decreaseStickerVO>
    <taxOfficeCod>04.20</taxOfficeCod>
 <vehicleDetailsVOList>
    <VehicleDetailsVO>
 <chassis>878JHJH</chassis>
<circulationTax>6750</circulationTax>
<cylinderCapacity>De 1.801 c.c. a 2.400 c.c.</cylinderCapacity>
<registration>LD-11-11-KK</registration>
<registrationDate>2019-01-01</registrationDate>
<sealNum>K</sealNum>
<vehicleBrand>K</vehicleBrand>
<vehicleExemption>false</vehicleExemption>
<vehicleModel>K</vehicleModel>
<vehicleType>Ligeiros</vehicleType>
    </VehicleDetailsVO>
    <VehicleDetailsVO>
<chassis>878JHJHJ</chassis>
<circulationTax>2450</circulationTax>
<cylinderCapacity>De 126 c.c. a 450 c.c.</cylinderCapacity>
<registration>LDA-44-44</registration>
<registrationDate>2019-01-01</registrationDate>
<sealNum>K</sealNum>
<vehicleBrand>K</vehicleBrand>
<vehicleExemption>false</vehicleExemption>
<vehicleModel>K</vehicleModel>
<vehicleType>Motociclos</vehicleType>
    </VehicleDetailsVO>
     </vehicleDetailsVOList>
 </decreaseStickerVO>
```

using the XSL

XSL Sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/decreaseStickerVO">
<decreaseStickerVO>
<taxOfficeCod>
  <xsl:value-of select="taxOfficeCod"/>
  </taxOfficeCod>
    <vehicleDetailsVOList>
      <xsl:for-each select="VehicleDetailsVO">
        <VehicleDetailsVO>
          <chassis>
            <xsl:value-of select="chassis"/>
          </chassis>
          <circulationTax>
            <xsl:value-of select="circulationTax"/>
          </circulationTax>
          <cylinderCapacity>
            <xsl:value-of select="cylinderCapacity"/>
          </cylinderCapacity>
          <registration>
            <xsl:value-of select="registration"/>
          </registration>
          <registrationDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="registrationDate"/>
          </registrationDate>
          <sealNum>
            <xsl:value-of select="sealNum"/>
          </sealNum>
          <vehicleBrand>
            <xsl:value-of select="vehicleBrand"/>
          </vehicleBrand>
          <vehicleExemption>
            <xsl:value-of select="vehicleExemption"/>
          </vehicleExemption>
          <vehicleModel>
            <xsl:value-of select="vehicleModel"/>
          </vehicleModel>
          <vehicleType>
            <xsl:value-of select="vehicleType"/>
          </vehicleType>
        </VehicleDetailsVO>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </vehicleDetailsVOList>
</decreaseStickerVO>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to the XML below

XML: 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<decreaseStickerVO>
 <taxOfficeCod>04.20</taxOfficeCod>
<vehicleDetailsVOList>
<VehicleDetailsVO>
<chassis>878JHJH</chassis>
<circulationTax>6750</circulationTax>
<cylinderCapacity>De 1.801 c.c. a 2.400 c.c.</cylinderCapacity>
<registration>LD-11-11-KK</registration>
<registrationDate>2019-01-01</registrationDate>
<sealNum>K</sealNum>
<vehicleBrand>K</vehicleBrand>
<vehicleExemption>false</vehicleExemption>
<vehicleModel>K</vehicleModel>
<vehicleType>Ligeiros</vehicleType>
</VehicleDetailsVO>
<VehicleDetailsVO>
<chassis>878JHJHJ</chassis>
<circulationTax>2450</circulationTax>
<cylinderCapacity>De 126 c.c. a 450 c.c.</cylinderCapacity>
<registration>LDA-44-44</registration>
<registrationDate>2019-01-01</registrationDate>
<sealNum>K</sealNum>
<vehicleBrand>K</vehicleBrand>
<vehicleExemption>false</vehicleExemption>
<vehicleModel>K</vehicleModel>
<vehicleType>Motociclos</vehicleType>
</VehicleDetailsVO>
</vehicleDetailsVOList>
</decreaseStickerVO>
```

But getting the result

```
<decreaseStickerVO>
<taxOfficeCod>04.20</taxOfficeCod>
<vehicleDetailsVOList/>
</decreaseStickerVO>
```

Please suggest what to change my XSL template to get the required result.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` is not a "tag" -  it's an XML declaration. Your stylesheet says `omit-xml-declaration="yes"`, so you're not getting it in the output.

Comment: Thanks for your response. After removing the omit-xml-declaration="yes". I am still not getting the desired output. Can you please suggest what more needs to be changed in my stylesheet.

Comment: Also look at the last comment in the accepted answer of the duplicate. It has a good note about serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why most of your result is empty is that you do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="VehicleDetailsVO">
```

from the context of:

```
<xsl:template match="/decreaseStickerVO">
```

The current node, `decreaseStickerVO` has no `VehicleDetailsVO`  children, so your `xsl:for-each` instruction selects nothing. You will get a different result if you do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="vehicleDetailsVOList/VehicleDetailsVO">
```

---

But if - as it seems - you want to keep everything in the existing XML as is, then you could do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or even shorter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```